# SFTP Server Host on Different Network

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm a noob to setting up servers, so please bear with me! This feels like it should be a simple answer, but for the life of me I can't find a solution anywhere I look.

I'm going to be setting up a full time server soon, but in the meantime I need a SFTP location. I'm planning on using my laptop for this for the time being.

I've gotten the SFTP location set up properly on my Laptop. I've tested it and confirmed functionality by using WinSCP on my Desktop to log into the SFTP location using the Laptops IPv4.

The problem is that I want people to be able to access the SFTP location from other networks. When I move my Laptop to a different network, I of course can't log in to the SFTP using the IPv4 anymore. My question is: **What host name do I have to use to get to the SFTP location of a computer on a different network?**

I tried the IPv4, but of course that's the wrong thing to use when off network.

Comment: Different network in what sense? Home vs office? Different offices in the same corp building? Different buildings entirely? Home WiFi main router vs home WiFi extender? Different homes?

Answer (score 0):

> What host name do I have to use to get to the SFTP location of a computer on a different network?

Host *name* is secondary, and not useful in this case at all – literally all that a hostname does is that it gets translated to an IP address. Meaning, if the laptop already has *some* IP address that you could reach, *then* you can try applying a name to it for convenience; but if the laptop doesn't have a usable address, no amount of hostnames will help with that.

With IPv4 the most common situation is that devices on a household or office LAN do not have any addresses reachable from outside, except for the router which does have a public IPv4 address. Any inbound connection requires you to set up "port forwarding" on that router, so that you could externally connect to the *router's* public IPv4 address and it'd translate that connection towards the laptop's internal address.

(If you do this, keep in mind that usually "port forwarding" works *only* externally – not from within the same network.)

(Usually not an issue for servers within datacenters, as those *do* get dedicated public IPv4 addresses that you can just connect to directly.)

This is also made increasingly troublesome by the fact that more and more ISPs have switched to CGNAT operation and stopped assigning public IP addresses to residential customers *completely* – not even the one for the router. (If your ISP has adopted CGNAT, sometimes you can call them and order an IP address as an extra feature, but usually you can't.) In those situations the answer is "literally none".

Some residential routers have a "dynamic DNS" feature that gives them a hostname, but it has the same restrictions as the actual IP address it resolves to; it still requires "port forwarding" and it still can't bypass CGNAT (i.e. the absence of any usable IPv4 address).

If your laptop has an IPv6 address *and* you're connecting from a network that also has IPv6, it's simpler – make sure the firewall permits the connection (which often still involves configuring the router), then just connect to the laptop's IPv6 address. Unfortunately, 25 years in, the IPv6 coverage still isn't great.

The last remaining option is to set up some kind of *outbound* VPN from the laptop, either one that directly gives you a public IPv4 address, or one that offers the same "port forwarding" through the VPN provider, or finally a simple internal-only VPN that both the client *and* the laptop must connect to in order to reach each other. (For the latter, a "mesh VPN" can be useful when you don't have any place to set up a standard VPN server.)